# How to access to BindingSource current of another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to access like this:

- Form 1: I wrote a method, it returns value bindingsource.current

  ```
  public ViewHocKy getHocKyCurrent()
  {
      return bindingSourceHocKy.Current as ViewHocKy; // value exists
  }
  ```
- Form 2: I wrote

  ```
      Form1 frm = new frmThongTin();
      ViewHocKy a = frm.getHocKyCurrent();// but value is null
  ```

  I don't know why value of a is null.Can help me?

I want to create public control in parent form and in child form, I access and get value of the control.
Can support for me the best way.I don't want Initialize forms when every times I get value from BindingDatasource.
Thanks all.

Comment: Are you sure that `bindingSourceHocKy` has a value when you're calling `getHocKyCurrent()`?  I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Sure! I debug and see value of bindingsource.Current and don't have any errors. But in another form when I call method getHocKyCurrent() value is null.I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

try like this.. it may be help you, in your getHocKyCurrent(), this will return the current binding source. and also try to set bindingsource control as public, so that it will be visible in another form.

```
return this.bindingSourceHocKy.Current as ViewHocKy;
```

Comment: I try like you say,but it's not change.BindingDatasource is public.I edit in partial class of design from.but thanks.